# How Can I read 4 sensor at the same time on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: multitasking, raspberry-pi4, rtos

I am new to raspberry pi, I was coding FREETOS on stm32f4 thanks for cube IDE.
I have 4 sensors (BNO055,MPU9250, MS5611, BME-280) plugged to raspberry pi 4 with shield. Also, I will do control of the valves with sensors data.
I do research about multitasking on raspi but sources is not enough.
So how I can do this system?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "at the same time" or why you think you need multitasking.  All these sensors use I2C and/or SPI interfaces.  If any of the sensors are sharing an I2C/SPI bus then you _cannot_ read those sensors at _literally_ "the same time".  Instead you have to serialize the communications and read one sensor after another.  If the sensor communications is serialized then do you really need multitasking?  Why not read one sensor after the other in a single task?

Comment: Unless you are running something other the Linux on the Pi this is mistagged [RTOS] .  Other that the fact that you have a previous implementation on an RTOS, the question is not about RTOS.

Answer (score 0):

Linux has two forms of multi-tasking.  Multiprocessing (running multiple independently linked executables simultaneously), and multi-threading (multiple threads of execution within a single process).  Multi-threading is most similar to the multi-tasking you are perhaps familiar with in FreeRTOS and most likley what you need here.

The basic API for multi-threading is pthreads (or POSIX threads), although you might consider language specific support for threads such as C++ `std::thread` *el al*: for example: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread.